# How to enforce www. -> https://www. on GAE with nodejs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to enforce www.example.com -> https://www.example.com & example.com-> https://example.com redirect on Google App Engine on NodeJS. I am already enforcing http:// -> https:// within express and it works as it should.

All of the existing solutions out there use a rewrite rule on nginx, however, I am not sure I can modify the nginx_proxy docker container that is running in the instance with this rewrite rule.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: You've mentioned the Nginx rule, I assume that you are running on the Flexible environment?

Comment: Yes I am running on a flexible environment.

Comment: It looks like it can be done from app side with something like this [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#forcing_https_connections], have you considered it? As far as I know, you must handle your own redirects on Flexible, where as in Standard there is an option that you can put in the app.yaml file.